# Mac WiFI connection sharing to router

Tags: macos, router, internet-sharing

I am trying to share my Macs WiFi connection to a linksys wrt54g router but nothing seems to be working.

When I plug the ethernet cord from the Mac into the internet port of the router the ethernet icon is yellow and gives me the following error: `Ethernet has a self-assigned IP address and will not be able to connect to the internet.`

I have my Wifi connect sharing to the ethernet port properly. Here are the fixes i've attemped:

- Reset the router to factory settings
- Tried turning off the Passive FTP option in the advance->proxies tab of both ethernet and Wifi
- Tried deleting com.apple.alf.plist and rebooting the computer
- Tried setting the router from a gateway to a router setting and plugging the wire both into the internet port and a standard lan port with no success

Any ideas why the router is not working with the internet sharing?